# Excel drowpdownlist in different cell after running VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a relative large Excel file. There are about 500 rows and 2 columns with a lot of text in each cel. Some cells contain a dropdownlist. Al the data is put in a table.

After I sort the table, somehow the drowpdownlist of one cell shifts to another cell, what shouldn't be possible.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on if we can't see the code you're using. Care to share it?

Comment: I just discovered that it also happens when I manually sort the table. I unfortunately cannot share the file... I could try to recreate the problem in a file with some random text.

Comment: Are you using controls from the Developer tab on your sheet or are you referring to dropdowns caused by the Data Validation feature?

Comment: I use the dropdownlist with the data validation feature

Comment: DO all cells in one column contain the same Data Validation rule or do you have different DV rules on different rows (not recommended in a table)?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/q/461363/1059206) might be helpfull. But doubt it. Having a validation list in a single cell, then sort the table will stay messy.

Comment: About 50 rows contain different validation lists. Some of the lists refer to cells with more than 255 characters.

Comment: The essence of a table is the similarity of data in its columns. If you have different validation lists in the same column that would be asking for trouble. Bear in mind that the Sort looks at the cell value. In a table, the format of cells in a column should be interchangeable. Validation is part of the format.